# How to call a view in a twig.template not page

Tags: views, theming, 8

I don't find good info on how to call for an existing view
in a particular twig.template (NOT the PAGE.HTML.TWIG!!!!).

The systemname of my view is this: testfeest

So I find sollutions online and tried them:

1. {{ testfeest }} not working
2. {{ content.testfeest }} not working
3. {{ view.testfeest }} also not working

Keep in mind that:

- I don't want to create a extra block of region for this
- The view will be placed not in the page template but a node template

Hope somebody can help me...
Thanks for reading.
Kristof

Answer (score 1):

One very simple method is to install the [Twig Tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak) module and use:

```
{{ drupal_view('testfeest', 'display_id') }}
```

Comment: I tried this and did not work... then I removed the part 'display_id' and it worked good!!! Thanks man, for the big tip and sollution. So this is what I used {{ drupal_view('testfeest') }}

Comment: `display_id` should be replaced with the display id within the view, not literally (if you passed "display_id").

Comment: You need to replace display_id with the machine name of the display from your view - but it'll fallback to the default if there's only one, that's probably why it works that way

Comment: Okay, I thought already that i had to replace 'display_id' with some kind of a ID :-) But i didn't find an id of my view... only the system name... Where can i see/find the ID of the view?

Comment: If you edit the display it should be in the URL - but if there's only one it might just default to not show that. I think there's a setting to control it in the Views global config page

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a new variable for the template in question and use [views_embed_view](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.module/function/views_embed_view/8.3.x):

```
function mytheme_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  // check for node type...
    $variables['myview'] = views_embed_view('view_id', 'display_id', $args);
  // endcheck
}
```

Clear the cache, then in the node twig you can output it:

`{{ myview }}`

Comment: Thanks for sharing this! This looks for me a as front developer more complicated. But where do you place this code?  In the same twig.content.template. Should I place PHP tags around it? Is not a convenience not to use PHP in D8 templates? But either way, thanks for the reply!

Comment: No. It goes in the .theme file. You cannot use php code in twig templates.